# Silverlight or WPF controls that take xml

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0, wpf-controls, silverlight-toolkit

Is there any silverlight or wpf grid type(ish) controls that take raw xml as input, i.e. map xml elements/attributes to grid fields.

Thanks.
 Bob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [XmlDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.aspx)?  [Here's an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx#S5) about using it.